# port phpmyadmin and openerp

Tags: postgresql, phpmyadmin, odoo

I newbie in PHP on Ubuntu, My computer already installed OpenERP and it using PosgresSQL as database, can I installed PhpMyadmin ?

how to cope if the port is a clash between two databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem in installing **phpmyadmin + mysql**, mysql and postgresql listen on different ports so there won't be any clash.

Comment: but why SQL Server and OpenERP the port clash ?

Answer (score -1):

It may be due to server process is already running so you need to kill that process but i am not sure may it work for you.

please try this command

ps ax | grep postmaster or similar to determine any process already running on server.